SelectedFilesChanged event never fires on DxUpload component for Blazor
I tried implementing the file uploader component from DevExpress like this:
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div id="file-upload-dropzone" class="card custom-dropzone rounded-3 w-100 m-0">
    <span class="drop-file-icon mb-3"></span>
    <span class="drop-file-label">Drop image(s) anywhere to upload</span><span class="m-1">or</span>
    <DxButton Id="file-upload-browse-button"
              CssClass="m-1"
              RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Primary"
              Text="Browse" />
</div>
<DxUpload Name="file"
          Visible="@UploadVisible"
          ExternalSelectButtonCssSelector="#file-upload-browse-button"
          ExternalDropZoneCssSelector="#file-upload-dropzone"
          ExternalDropZoneDragOverCssClass="custom-dropzone-hover"
          UploadUrl="https://localhost:7226/api/Upload/Upload/"
          SelectedFilesChanged="@SelectedFilesChanged"
          MaxFileSize="15000000">
</DxUpload>

@code {
    bool UploadVisible { get; set; } = false;
    protected void SelectedFilesChanged(IEnumerable<UploadFileInfo> files)
    {
        UploadVisible = files.ToList().Count > 0;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
    protected string GetUploadUrl(string url)
    {
        var test = NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(url).AbsoluteUri;
        return test;
    }
}


The styling is great, and the windows file-selector window opens when I click the button, but the SelectedFilesChanged event never fires.
I basically followed the exact example here.
What have I missed?

I figured it out. Turns out the solution was a combination of things. For one I previously had a format restriction like this:
AcceptedFileTypes="@(new List<string> { "ndpi", "scn", "svs", "czi" })">
I didn't add the dots before the file format, which was the base of my error. I tried removing the restriction but it didn't work. This turns out to because I only used the Hot Reload function and not restarting the app. For some reason that is not enough.
